# GridView throw eventArgument parameter is too long when Selecting all rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, sharepoint-2013

I have one GridView control on my asp page. Based on requirement pagination is not enabled on that grid so in production environment where there are lots of records available. They load properly on Grid. But as soon as I click on Select all check box. I get this error message. **An unexpected error has occurred. eventArgument parameter is too long Please check the event log or contact your administrator.**
Is there any memory setting I can tweak to handle large data. My website is hosted on sharepoint.
[image]

Comment: what's code written in checkbox event?

Comment: Nothing is written on that checkbox.  I have not override or associate any event on that checkbox click. Just multiselect property is true for this grid.